# Nearby user location map not loading while using foursquare api

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to get the nearby venues using foursquare api

WARNING: Passed MKUserLocation to -[MKMapView removeAnnotation:]. Use -[MKMapView setShowsUserLocation:NO] instead

I am getting this warning i changed the code as mentioned but still the venues are not loading

Comment: The problem is probably in the part of your code where you try to load the venus. Why don't you talk about that bit instead of the problem you already fixed and is unrelated to the venues?

Comment: its actually showing this error while i run on ios7 simulator. It works well in all other simulators. May be due to some deprecated codes. I will find it, thanks anyways Craig.